# In JMeter why is a redirected sample disabled?

Tags: redirect, jmeter

I've made a recording of actions on various web pages.

Submitting a large form causes a redirect to be recorded in JMeter under the Recording Controller.

```
Detected a redirect from the previous sample
```

In the image below, the client/create page POSTs the form data and receives a 302 redirect from the server to the create/confirm page.
JMeter is automatically disabling this GET redirect page (in grey below) as (presumably) it's something that is sent automatically and not required to be sent by the recording

[image]

When I replay this (using the validate option), the redirected page doesn't appear. Screen shot from View Results Tree:

[image]

This is a particular issue as the page contains a value that I need to extract for subsequent requests (accountselection being one).

Simply re-enabling the disabled redirect page doesn't work. Nor does blindly putting a regular expression extractor on it (as the page is disabled).

As it doesn't appear in the 'View Results Tree' I can't see the contents of the response either .

How do I get at the value in the body of the redirected page?

Comment: Your description is unclear, hence you are not getting any answers. What's the flow of the HTTP requests? is "redirect" you talking about an HTTP 301/302/... redirect and if yes, from where to where? if not, what do you mean by "redirect page"? what does it mean "the page is disabled"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When recording JMeter intentionally disables Http Request that are the result of a redirect.

Now you problem is that you most probably didn't variabilize some id used for the success of the initial request leading to redirect.

Check all parameters and headers sent in this first request and make them variable when needed:

- Use a post processor on the previous(can be any preceding request) request to extract the value in varName (example)
- Use ${varName} to inject it

This concept is called correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the particular request from which redirect occurs.

Find the option **"Follow Redirects"** under Path.

Check it if not checked. Now rerun the script.